# Split a string text by element class using php and keeping all original text inside array

Tags: php

i'd like to split a long text into chunks. I need to split by element class (element can be h, p, span, div or others unknown tag).
So, for example, if I got a string like:

```
$string = 'Hi this is a long <span class="cut">string</span> and I need to <span class="cut">split it into chunks</span> and I need help for <span class="cut">this</span>';
```

I'd like to split by `cut` class, into array, keeping all texts:
Expected result:

```
$array(
   0 => 'Hi this is a long ',
   1 => '<span class="cut">string</span>',
   2 => ' and I need to ',
   3 => '<span class="cut">split it into chunks</span>',
   4 => ' and I need help for ',
   5 => '<span class="cut">this</span>'
);
```

I don't find any example on the web.

I find only this one by it find only elements by class and exclude all other text and I don't know if it is usefull for my purpose:

```
 $domdocument = new DOMDocument();
 $domdocument->loadHTML($contenuto);
 $a = new DOMXPath($domdocument);
 $elements = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' cut')]");

 for ($i = $elements->length - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
    var_dump($elements->item($i)->firstChild->nodeValue);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try a `preg_match_all` regex match all approach here:

```php
$string = 'Hi this is a long <span class="cut">string</span> and I need to <span class="cut">split it into chunks</span> and I need help for <span class="cut">this</span>';
preg_match_all("/<(\w+).*?>.*?<\/\\1>|.*?(?=<|$)/", $string, $matches);
$lines = $matches[0];
array_pop($lines);
print_r($lines);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hi this is a long 
    [1] => <span class="cut">string</span>
    [2] =>  and I need to 
    [3] => <span class="cut">split it into chunks</span>
    [4] =>  and I need help for 
    [5] => <span class="cut">this</span>
)
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
<(\w+).*?>  an HTML tag
.*?         any content
<\/\\1>     closing tag
|           OR
.*?         any other content until reaching, but not including
(?=<|$)     the next HTML tag or the end of the input
```

Comment: Hi @tim, thanks for your help. I tried it on phptester.net but it seems it cutout <span class="cut">   and </span>. UPDATE ok tried in my localhost...it works!! thanks

Comment: ... then remove the `array_pop($lines);` step in my code.  For your input, I was getting an additional array element at the end which we don't want.

Comment: UPDATE2: Ops I tried it but I see that '</span>' is splitted inside next string: array (size=13)
  0 => string 'Hi this is a long ' (length=18)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '<span class="cut">string' (length=24)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '</span> and I need to ' (length=22)
  5 => string '' (length=0)
  6 => string '<span class="cut">split it into chunks' (length=38)
  7 => string '' (length=0)
  8 => string '</span> and I need help for ' (length=28)
  9 => string ''
  10 => string '<span class="cut">this'
  11 => string ''
  12 => string '</span>'

Comment: My answer works with the data you actually did provide above, [see this demo](https://rextester.com/GPYIL85838).  You can update the demo if you find an edge case where the logic breaks, and paste the link here.

Comment: ok thanks. probably something wrong using php 8 cause using same string I get other output