# Split and keep a string text by element class using php

Tags: php

i'd like to split a long text into chunks. I need to split by tag class (tags can be h, p, span, div or others tag). So, for example, if I got a string like:

```
$string = 'Hi this is a <h1><strong>long</strong><h1> <span class="cut">string</span> and I need to <p class="cut">split it into chunks</p> and I need help for <span class="cut">this</span>';
```

I'd like to split by `cut` class, into array, keeping all texts: Expected result:

```
$array(
 0 => 'Hi this is a <h1><strong>long</strong><h1> ',
 1 => '<span class="cut">string</span>',
 2 => ' and I need to ',
 3 => '<p class="cut">split it into chunks</p>',
 4 => ' and I need help for ',
 5 => '<span class="cut">this</span>'
);
```

I've already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009696/split-a-string-text-by-element-class-using-php-and-keeping-all-original-text-ins/72009832) but solution is not based on "class" but only by "tag":

```
$string = 'Hi this is a <h1><strong>long</strong><h1> <span class="cut">string</span> and I need to <p class="cut">split it into chunks</p> and I need help for <span class="cut">this</span>';
preg_match_all("/<(\w+).*?>.*?<\/\\1>|.*?(?=<|$)/", $string, $matches);
$lines = $matches[0];
array_pop($lines);
print_r($lines);
```

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse HTML, they aren't suited for that. Use a proper parser instead, [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/) will do the job for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

array_walk_recursive($lines, function(&$v) { $v = htmlspecialchars($v); });

```
$string = 'Hi this is a <h1><strong>long</strong><h1> <span class="cut">string</span> and I need to <p class="cut">split it into chunks</p> and I need help for <span class="cut">this</span>';
preg_match_all("/<(\w+).*?>.*?<\/\\1>|.*?(?=<|$)/", $string, $matches);
$lines = $matches[0];
array_pop($lines);
array_walk_recursive($lines, function(&$v) { $v = htmlspecialchars($v); });
print_r($lines);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, same problem... scripts doesn't split by "cut" class.... but only by tags.....